# elevatezoom mouse position — the struggle is real

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, mouse-position

I am using [elevatezoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom) for a project and I need to get the mouse position while the picture is zoomed in. I tried a lot of different ideas but I always get `undefined` or `NaN`. Can you tell me why?

Look at this example:

```
$('#zoomPicture').elevateZoom({
  scrollZoom : true,
  zoomWindowFadeIn: 250,
  zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
  responsive: true,
  easing: true,
  easingDuration: 50,
  borderSize: 1,
  zoomWindowWidth: 400,
  zoomWindowHeight: 400,
});

$("#zoomPicture").bind("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.pageX);
  console.log(e.pageY);
}); // -> undefined
```

Comment: Isn’t it called `pageX` instead of `PageX` and `pageY` instead of `PageY`?

Comment: It is. But this does not solve the problem - still getting 'undefined' . Thanks for editing my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please let me know if the below code works for you

```
$(document).bind("click", "#zoomPicture", function(e) {
  console.log(e.pageX);
  console.log(e.pageY);
});
```

Does this link help you with your question: [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

The object `ElevateZoom.self.nzOffset` contain the x and y coordinates of the image.

You can see the values by using:

```
console.log( ElevateZoom.self.nzOffset );
```

With this information you can implement the `jQuery.on("click", function(){ //stuff here })`

Hope I have helped.

Cya